# Change port of databricks-connect to 443

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I have a Databricks cluster with 10.4 runtime, when I configure `databricks-connect configure` I put all the information needed and using the default port 15001, `databricks-connect test` works.

But changing the port to 443 does not work, I tried to do a pyspark session but it also fails:

```
: com.databricks.service.SparkServiceConnectionException: Invalid port (443) or invalid token:

The port you specified is either being used already or invalid.
Port: The port that Databricks Connect connects to
  - The default Databricks Connect port is 15001
  - Get current value: spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.port")
  - Set via conf: spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.service.port", <your port>")
```

I added a configuration on my cluster (spark config)

> spark.databricks.service.server.enabled true

> spark.databricks.service.port 443

But it did not work.

Why doesn't it work?
The reason why I want to change to port 443 is simple, my github action workflows is on a self-hosted worker which is behind a firewall that block the port 15001, so I'm trying to find a solution to use a port which is opened.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following approach in Databricks Notebook using the content below:

**1st Approach:**

`spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.service.server.enabled", "true") spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.service.port", "443")`

**Results:**

```
print(spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.server.enabled"))
print(spark.conf.get("spark.databricks.service.port"))
```

```
true
443
```

**2nd Approach:**

In the cluster configuration page:

**Edit** > **Advanced settings** > **Spark configuration**

[image]

After adding the Spark configuration, confirm and restart the cluster.

Comment: I've did exaclty as you, and it did not work. I've veryfied that my ".databricks-connect" file is correclty configure with `443` port on the correct cluster. The token is correct because this same token is working with default port `15001`. But if I put all values to `15001` in spark config (cluster and driver + databricks-connect), then it works correclty. It tried to take a un unset port by my computer `15002`, but still doesn't work